# Convert PHP 5.3 anonymous function to work with PHP < 5.3

Tags: php, anonymous-function

This is a function that cause error says :
"syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in C:\AppServ\www\BAR\php\php-barcode.php on line 166"

```
 // GD barcode renderer
    private static function digitToGDRenderer($gd, $color, $xi, $yi, $angle, $mw, $mh, $digit){
        $fn = function($points) use ($gd, $color) {
            imagefilledpolygon($gd, $points, 4, $color);
        };
        return self::digitToRenderer($fn, $xi, $yi, $angle, $mw, $mh, $digit);
    }
```

I want to convert it to work in php 5.2 .. thanks alot

Comment: I'm afraid digitToRenderer requires a closure as first argument, so you need to change it as well

Comment: You could use `create_function()` and `var_export` to pass your extra vars through.

Comment: You really should try to upgrade to a supported version of PHP if possible

Comment: @MarkBaker unfortunately PHP V5.3 is not supported in Appserv yet .

Comment: I very much doubt that appserv will ever support any other versions of PHP, it's pretty dead from all accounts, and has been for the best part of 4 years..... so you shouldn't really rely on it any more

Comment: @user2930653 Then you should hit them with a hammer or change to another stack-provider. V5.2 is long out of support. Even 5.3 is already meant to die. You should target 5.4 or even 5.5 as it appears to be (in PHP-terms) quite stable, many serious hosting-providers and stack-creators are supporting atleast one of these officially maintained release branches.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an extra class for this in order to encapsulate data and functionality:

```
class RendererAction {
    protected $gd;
    protected $color;

    public function __construct($gd, $color) {
        $this->gd = $gd;
        $this->color = $color;
    }

    public function run($points) {
        imagefilledpolygon($this->gd, $points, 4, $this->color);
    }
}
```

Change `digitToGDRenderer` to :

```
private static function digitToGDRenderer($gd, $color, $xi, $yi, $angle, $mw, $mh, $digit){
    $action = new RendererAction($gd, $color);
    return self::digitToRenderer($action, $xi, $yi, $angle, $mw, $mh, $digit);
}
```

... and change `self::digitToRenderer` in a way that it calls `run($points)` on `$action`.

---

This is not exactly the same as using a closure but can be used as a workaround in most cases.